# React Native, error " Unable to resolve "./PathToComponent " from "/PathToOtherComponent""

Tags: react-native, path, components

While doing an App in React Native, I came across this error : "Unable to resolve "./CompentName" from "Components/OtherComponentName.js".

I understand that my error comes from the way I wrote the path for my component import, but looking at my folder design I can't seem to understand why.

Does any of you may, please, have an answer for this silly question ?

Here is my fodler design,I am trying to use the component " FilmItem" in the file "Search.js"
[fodler design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpTI6.png)

Here is my import/export : 
-"export default FilmItem"
 - "import FilmItem from './FilmItem.js' "

And here is the full error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9VLm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick on another forum

- remove node_modules: rm -rf node_modules
- clear react-native cache and watchman: rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && watchman watch-del-all"
- install back all packages: yarn install

Then finally react-native run-android worked.